# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException using dropbox v2 core api java

Tags: java, jackson, dropbox-api

I have a program that is already working a couple of years but it is not working anymore now due to a jackson.core error and I can not figure out why it is thrown.

Chunck of code that throws the error (**last line**):

```
//Build inputstream
if(yearDirCheck == true && monthDirCheck == true){
//The folder already exists, upload the file directly
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(docname)) {
FileMetadata metadata = client.files().uploadBuilder(path + "/" + jaar + "/"+ maand +"/" + docname)
    .uploadAndFinish(in);
} 
catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(maakPDF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}  
mail.verzendOverurenKaart(Technician, client.sharing().createSharedLinkWithSettings(path + "/" + jaar + "/"+ maand +"/" + docname).getUrl());
```

}

**The error i get:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException.<init>(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser, java.lang.String)'
at com.dropbox.core.stone.StoneSerializer.expectEndObject(StoneSerializer.java:98)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.LinkPermissions$Serializer.deserialize(LinkPermissions.java:310)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.LinkPermissions$Serializer.deserialize(LinkPermissions.java:242)
at com.dropbox.core.stone.StructSerializer.deserialize(StructSerializer.java:21)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.FileLinkMetadata$Serializer.deserialize(FileLinkMetadata.java:455)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.SharedLinkMetadata$Serializer.deserialize(SharedLinkMetadata.java:494)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.SharedLinkMetadata$Serializer.deserialize(SharedLinkMetadata.java:381)
at com.dropbox.core.stone.StructSerializer.deserialize(StructSerializer.java:21)
at com.dropbox.core.stone.StoneSerializer.deserialize(StoneSerializer.java:66)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2$1.execute(DbxRawClientV2.java:103)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.executeRetriable(DbxRawClientV2.java:252)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.rpcStyle(DbxRawClientV2.java:97)
```

I am using the jackson-core-2.6.1 library and thus the dorpbox v2 core api in java. Not using maven or gradle or anything.

[image: Updated list of libs]

Comment: show your pom.xml please

Comment: @StepanShcherbakov I am not using maven, do not have pom. I add a snippet with the libs i use. Thanks!

Comment: What did you change since it was working? Did you add any libs or code? Are the libaries you use at compile time equal with the ones you use at runtime?

Comment: @PSandro I did not change anything as far as i know

Comment: Where do you run this program? Are the libaries at runtime the same as the ones at compile time (in your screenshot above). Depending on where you execute this program, there might be a different version of jackson-core which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your libs, you have two `jackson-core` dependencies. 2.6.1 and 2.7.4.
Usually this kind of exception is associated with dependencies conflicts, so removing one should fix it.

Comment: thanks for the reply, did this but it is still not working. Also, this was also like this when it was still working.